# How can I set a transition for an element losing focus

Tags: css

I have a simple transition from black to dark grey like so:

```
.navbar .logo:hover {
    -o-transition: 1s;  
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -moz-tranistion: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 0.2s;

    color: darkgrey;

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yD46F/10/

But when I stop hovering, it instantly turns back to black, instead of transitioning back to black, how can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move your transitions to a separate CSS rule:

```
.navbar .logo {
    -o-transition: 1s;  
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -moz-tranistion: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

The issue there is that you are currently assigning transitions to an element with pseudo-class `:hover`. So when the mouse moves from the element, it does not have `:hover` class anymore => does not have `transition` style properties.